# Create pull request from same branch to multiple branches

Tags: git

We have a `dev` branch and `master` branch. When there is hotfix we checkout new branch say `hotfix-1` from `master` and raise pull request to `master` branch. We also want to merge only this commit changes to the `dev` branch. So we would like to create a pull request from `hotfix-1` to the `dev` branch too.

However, we are unable to do create a pull request from the same branch to `dev` because it is ahead and getting merge conflicts and if we update `hotfix-1` with dev changes it will reflect master commit. What would be the solution to this? Do we need to create `hotfix-dev-1` cherry-pick these latest commit changes and create a pull request to `dev`? Any helps is greatly appreciated.

If we have new branch added in between say `support` should we need to create `hotfix-2`? Does this branching model scale when more number of long-lived branches introduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do we need to create hotfix-dev-1 cherry-pick these latest commit changes and create a pull request to dev?

If a pull request (so I presume GitHub) is how the change gets into both of your branches: In short, yes.  Pull request is to merge changes on the branch starting at the base it forked off from the target branch.

Well at least in the remote branch where you create a pull request. Locally, let's assume you got one commit on top of `master` which you want to have in `dev`. You can switch to dev:

```
git checkout dev
```

Perhaps make sure you're at the same state as the remote repo:

```
git pull
```

Cherry-pick `HEAD` of master:

```
git cherry-pick master
```

And now you can push it into the a new branch in the remote repository:

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/hotfix-dev-1
```

You can create a PR against `dev` from that branch and you can locally reset your `dev` to its original state:

```
git reset --hard origin/dev
```

It doesn't really provide much advantage over just creating a branch to push from (and pruning it afterwards if you wish).